# Big problems with integer solutions

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving

"A and B are two rectangles with sides that have an integer value. The perimeter of A is two times the perimeter of B, and the area of B is two times the area of A. If one of the sides of A is 1, determinate all possible integer values of sides of the rectangles A and B".

I think this problem is easy but i can't figure it, the only thing that i determinate is if we evaluate the sides of A as x and 1 and the sides of B as y and z

We have a equation system like this:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
yz=2x \\ 
2y+2z=x+1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: What makes you refer to this as a "big problem"? If it's you having trouble, I should warn you that users on this site don't really like that kind of title - you should try to state the actual problem, or at least the context it comes from, like "Finding integer solutions to a system of equations," instead.

Comment: Your system seems to capture the conditions OK. Do you have any start on solving?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the first into the second, getting 
$$4y+4z=yz+2\\14=(y-4)(z-4)$$
and factor $14$